# Dynamic controls postback updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, user-controls, updatepanel, postback

I have a page of dynamic controls including textboxes, radiobuttons, checkboxes (all bind to a Panel).

I run my create control function on Page_init function.

So i have something like:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateControls();
    }

    protected void PopulateControls()
    {
        ....
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
         {
          ...create dynamic controls
         }
        Panel1.Controls.Add(dynamic controls);

    }
```

On postback (e.g. when i uncheck a checkbox) the screen jumps to the top.

Normally, when I am not using dynamic controls, I just put **UpdatePanel/ContentTemplate** around each of the control. But since I am not able to do that now, is there a way to stop the page from jumping to the top on postback?

Thanks!

Comment: You have `UpdatePanel` in the title, the question and in the tag, but are you using one?

Comment: I want to know how to use it dynamically?

Comment: Yes, but if you replace `Panel1` with an `UpdatePanel` it should work. Have you tried it? You have to add them to the [`ContentTemplateContainer.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.contenttemplatecontainer.aspx).

Comment: Your code `Panel1.Controls.Add(dynamic controls);` shows that you are using **Panel** rather than **UpdatePanel**. Use **UpdatePanel** in the same way as you are using Panel, the only exception would be that you will be adding controls to the ItemTemplate rather than the Panel. Hope this helps.

Comment: @LiaqatG: You cannot add controls to an UpdatePanel via `Controls.Add`, that will raise an `InvalidOperationException`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.controls.aspx

Comment: @tim-schmelter Please read the full comment, I have mentioned the ItemTemplate (ContentTemplateContainer) in it. What I have suggested is to replace the Panel with UpdatePanel and vice versa. Thanks.

Comment: Guys, using your suggested solution didn't work - everytime I submit the form, the text I entered in the controls disappear. Also I can't uncheck the checkboxes...it keeps staying checked. Any ideas?

Comment: thanks guys - have it figured out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add controls dynamically to an `UpdatePanel`.
You have to add them to the [`ContentTemplateContainer.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.contenttemplatecontainer.aspx).

```
for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
 {
  ...create dynamic controls
 }
UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(dynamic controls);
```

Comment: @viv_acious: Of course you could also put a `Panel`into an `UpdatePanel` which was added declaratively and use `Controls.Add` on the panel.

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right because it's not working. On my .aspx page, I have the <UpdatePanel1><ContentTemplate> control. Then in my code-behind, I replaced my old Panel1 with your code for every dynamic controls. And now my textbox clears everytime there's postback and I'm unable to uncheck checkboxes! Any ideas?! Much appreciated!

Comment: dont worry Tim, I dont think the updatepanel was the culprit here! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(dynamic controls);
```

shows that you are using **Panel** rather than **UpdatePanel**. Use **UpdatePanel** in the same way as you are using Panel, the only exception would be that you will be adding controls to the **ItemTemplate** rather than the Panel. In the case of Panel, it holds the controls directly since it is a container while in case of UpdatePanel, it is it's **ContentTemplateContainer** that contains the properties or controls. Therefore you can use something like below instead of the above line.

```
UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(button1);
```

Please also make sure to include this line of code inside the body of your **for loop** if you are creating more than one controls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Liaqat, I've replaced my panel with UpdatePanel as you suggested and it's now acting weird - textbox clears on postback and i cannot uncheck checkboxes...any ideas how to fix this? much appreciated!

Comment: dont worry about it - i dont think the updatepanel was the issue here! thanks for all your help!